# A limit using the Euler number: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n!}{(n-i)!}\left(\frac{c}{n}\right)^{n-i}$

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, closed-form

What is answer of this limit and how can I get it? $c$ and $i$ are constants.
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n!}{(n-i)!}\left(\frac{c}{n}\right)^{n-i}$$
I guess it will envolve some Neper/the Euler number $e$. I tried to rearrange terms of factorial and exponents in a good way but I couldn't make any conclusion so I think couldn't find the nice shape of writing this expression.

Comment: Isn't $\;c\;$ given?

Comment: The question is unclear. You should at least describe what $c$ and $i$ are. For example, what range does $i$ belong to?

Comment: What is a neper?

Comment: Neperian logarithm, natural logarithm (I assume).

Comment: I think it should be clear that when nothing is mentioned extra about symbols, except $n$ which is appeared in the limit, the rest are constants!
By neper I mean neper number!

Comment: In Italian, the Neper number is the constant $e$. It's from [John Napier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Napier).

Comment: @H.W. Sorry, I only know English.

Comment: It turns out that $e$ plays no role here, since $\frac{n!}{(n-1)!}\le n^i$, and therefore our expression is $\le c^i (c/n)^{n-2i}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. We assume $c,i$ are any fixed real numbers.

By setting $\displaystyle u_n=\frac{n!}{(n-i)!}\left(\frac{c}{n}\right)^{n-i}$, one gets, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}&=\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1-i)!}\left(\frac{c}{n+1}\right)^{n+1-i}\cdot \frac{(n-i)!}{n!}\left(\frac{n}{c}\right)^{n-i}
\\\\&=\frac{(n+1)}{(n+1-i)}\cdot \frac{c}{n+1}\cdot \left(1+\frac1n \right)^{-n+i}
\\\\& \sim \frac{c}{e(n+1)}
\\\\& \to 0.
\end{align}
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: @H.W. bigger than $e$.

Comment: @Olivier Haven't you forgotten a factor $\frac{c}{n+1}$? When using Stirling, I found the original expression $u_n$ to be equivalent to $n^i\left(\frac{c}{n}\right)^{n-i}$, which goes to $0$ (quite fast) regardless of the value of $c$.

Comment: For an upper bound, one needs very little, since $n!/(n-i)!\le n^i$.

Comment: @ClementC. Edited. Thank you very much.